# Do we need to sign transaction for totalSupply also?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs-tx

I am using web3 and want to sign transactions made with ERC20 contract.

Comment: to read data from the blockchain you don't need to send a transaction

Answer (score 2):

Function `totalSupply` is constant (either `pure` or `view`, in this case - `view`).

As such, it doesn't change anything on the blockchain.

Therefore, is no transaction involved here whatsoever.

You just need to issue a Web3-RPC (a remote procedure call to the node via Web3 protocol).

And since there is no transaction involved, there is no need to sign one.

---

**Coding example using web3.js v1.x:**

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const ABI = [
    {
        "type"            : "function",
        "name"            : "totalSupply",
        "inputs"          : [],
        "outputs"         : [{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],
        "stateMutability" : "view",
        "payable"         : false,
        "constant"        : true // for backward-compatibility
    }
];

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3(<YourNodeUrl>);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, <YourContractAddress>);
    const totalSupply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
    console.log(totalSupply);
}

run();
```